# Randomly Disappearing Mount Point

Tags: linux, mount, autofs

I have 3 servers all with the same set of mount points. On one server loses it connection to the mount fairly often and the two other servers it never does. I cannot reconnect until I reboot the server. I have tried using both a static mount and autofs to connect.

The file server is sharing the folder with this statement in /etc/exports

```
/var/files/images 10.176.0.0/255.255.0.0(rw,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)
```

I am also sharing several other folders the same way, but this is the only one that is ever dropped.

Any ideas on what is wrong?

Comment: Anything in the output of dmesg or /var/log/messages?

Comment: Are all 3 servers using the same OS and version? Are 3 servers using the same NFS version?

Answer (score 1):

Try switching from a hard to soft mount flags.

Reconsider no_root_squash. It may be part of the problem (a user or app may be abusing privilege to kill the mount).

Look carefully for SELinux warnings of any kind.

Check and see if there are any files or subdirectories under the mount point, and use lsof to see if any process is keeping them open after mount is lost.

Post any log message here.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like maybe you're dropping packets somewhere?  Have you checked the counters on the switch and the output from

```
netstat -s eth0
```

If the server is in the same building, and can afford a few seconds of downtime, try replacing the ethernet cable.  Could also be that the switch is set to auto-negotiate, and the NIC is set to static (or vice-versa).

Comment: The only thing about it being a network issue is, why would one mount disappear and the 6 others I have continue working just fine?